# What are the two different times output from an XCTest run?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

When I run my set of unit tests (Xcode 9.2), it logs output like this:

```
Test Suite 'All tests' passed at 2017-12-13 14:16:27.947.
    Executed 319 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.372 (0.574) seconds
```

There are two times here, 0.372 and 0.574 seconds respectively.
Can anyone please tell me (or point me to anything that explains) what the two different values mean, and why there is a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `0.372` delta time is the effective time spent by the test cases runtime execution.

The second `0.574` is the effective time spent between the beginning and the end of the measurements.

Why a difference of `0.202` ? I suppose there is a `context switching` debt of some milliseconds, depending by the `Test Cases` and `Test Suites` cardinality.

Moreover, you may check here:
[image]
the `5.434` is the delta between `12.247` and `17.681`, so between the effective beginning of the unit testing and the end of the execution of the last `Test Suite`